# Is the durability of Sony SSM Autofocus Motors comparable to those from Canon L-series lenses?

Tags: sony, focus-motor

Are Sony SSM autofocus motors as durable and long lasting as the motors found on the Canon L series lenses?

I was told by a salesman that Sony puts quite a few motors in each lens. I see G master lenses failing in this regard.

Comment: I can't quite decode your question. Is it the case that you have good experience with the reliability of "L" lenses from Canon, and you are trying to determine if you can expect the same thing from Sony's SSM lenses?

Comment: I would remind you that anecdotal evidence, or any "mean time to failure" figures, don't tell you when any *specific* unit will/might fail.

Comment: Sony puts multiple motor in some of their lenses with the new style *linear* focusing motors. Are you sure that's not what the salesman was referencing?

Comment: I have had really good reliability with Canon L lenses in the past.   I would like to know if Sony g masters can hold up just as well.   I was told that sony   has improved their focus by wire systems and motors.  Looking for any known issues.   On another topic the mount craftmanship on the lens I purchsed is crap as seen in this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qGvlX9BtiTQ